# Filter CSV file and create new files based on contents of the original

Tags: vb.net, file, csv, filtering

The contents of the original file DOC.csv is the following:

```
AH08B/001319;F09351812;F09351812;F09351812;20131112;101009;10;3.30;15.00;0
AH08B/001319;F09351812;F09351812;F09351812;20131112;101009;10;3.30;15.00;0
AH08B/001320;F09351812;F09351812;F09351812;20131112;101271;400;1.30;5.00;10
```

Filtering that file by the first column, i need to obtain two new files:

File 1

```
AH08B/001319;F09351812;F09351812;F09351812;20131112;101009;10;3.30;15.00;0
AH08B/001319;F09351812;F09351812;F09351812;20131112;101009;10;3.30;15.00;0
```

File 2

```
AH08B/001320;F09351812;F09351812;F09351812;20131112;101271;400;1.30;5.00;10
```

What is the best approach that i can follow to obtain these results?

Comment: which element determines File 1 or File2???  There are multiple candidates it appears

Comment: I filter by the first column, that contains the "AH08B/0013XX"

Comment: I would Use LINQTOXML to create the two subLists http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=564

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the file isn't too large to fit in memory, something like this should work:

```
Dim groups = IO.File.ReadAllLines("DOC.csv").GroupBy(Function(x) x.Substring(0, x.IndexOf(";"c)))
For i = 0 To groups.Count - 1
    IO.File.WriteAllLines("DOC" & (i + 1).ToString.PadLeft(2, "0"c) & ".csv", groups(i).ToArray)
Next
```

If memory is an issue here's one way that will work:

```
Dim keys As New List(Of String)
Using sr As New IO.StreamReader("textfile1.txt")
    Do Until sr.EndOfStream
       Dim line = sr.ReadLine
        Dim key As String = line.Substring(0, line.IndexOf(";"c))
        If keys.Contains(key) Then
            IO.File.AppendAllText("DOC" & (keys.IndexOf(key) + 1).ToString.PadLeft(2, "0"c) & ".csv", line & vbNewLine)
        Else
            keys.Add(key)
            IO.File.WriteAllText("DOC" & keys.Count.ToString.PadLeft(2, "0"c) & ".csv", line & vbNewLine)
        End If
    Loop
End Using
```

Either way will create files with the lines grouped according to the first field and the filenames in the format of "DOCxx.csv".

Answer (score 1):

Below takes the first element from your csv file, creates a new file if one does not exist, and then adds the record to it. This processes row by row (e.g. not optimized for speed), but shouldn't run into memory constraints.

```
string fileName = "C:\\Temp\\T1.csv";
if (File.Exists(fileName))
{
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileName);
    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        string record = sr.ReadLine();
        string newFileName = "C:\\Temp\\" + record.Substring(0, record.IndexOf(";")) + ".csv";
        if (!File.Exists(newFileName))
        {
            File.Create(newFileName);
        }
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(newFileName, true);
        sw.WriteLine(record);
        sw.Close();
    }
    sr.Close();
}
```

Comment: There's only a warning when initializing the StreamWriter: An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll Additional information:The process cannot access the file'c:\temp\doc3.csv'because it is being used by another process.